# how to divide to date to get split one record to multiple records to get due dates in that year?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We want to split query in 6 parts Like; I have AMC of particular client and its agreement period is Annually(Yearly). AMC start date is (2018-01-22) and end date is (1/31/2019)  and Preventive maintenance(PM) are 6 in that year then PM date will be the start of the month and reminder date will be the 10 days before end date.
like this we want to generate records on agreement period Annually or Quarterly

We tried as below, but like this we have to use this code 6 or 12 times.

Query:

```
DECLARE @amcno  VARCHAR (50)    = 'ICT/2017-18/1';
DECLARE @strtdte    DATETIME    = '02/01/2018';
SELECT
      amcno
    , gstinno
    , [date]
    , custnme
    , adress
    , contprsn
    , agrmntype
    , strtdte
    , agrperod
    , bilngcycl
    , bilngperod
    , endate
    , status
    , DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, @strtdte))     AS pmdate
    , DATEADD(dd, -10, DATEADD(mm, 1, @strtdte))    AS reminder
    , 1
FROM
    TBL_AMC
WHERE
    amcno = @amcno;
```

Result:

```
ICT/2017-18/1   11  2018-01-22  MAHESH SHINDE   SATARA  MMS NON-COMPREHENSIVE   2018-01-22  MONTHLY BEFORE  MONTHLY 2018-01-23  ENABLED 2018-02-28 2018-02-19   1
```

Is there any way to split record into multiple records by dividing to it with single query?

expected result:-
Row Count= 6

```
  amcno         [date]        custnme     strtdte     endate       pmdate   reminder  count
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-01-22  2018-03-21  2018-03-21  2018-03-11    1
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-03-22  2018-05-21  2018-05-21  2018-05-11    2
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-05-22  2018-07-21  2018-07-21  2018-07-11    3
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-07-22  2018-09-21  2018-09-21  2018-09-11    4
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-09-22  2018-11-21  2018-11-21  2018-11-11    5
  ICT/2017-18/1  2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE 2018-11-22  2019-01-21  2019-01-21  2019-01-11    6
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please format your query and results so we can read them.

Comment: @HoneyBadger  Done...

Comment: It is formatted, but not so we can read it. I don't want to have to scroll so far...

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: "split record into multiple records" What do you mean by this precisely? What is the desired result? On what basis does this "splitting" occur? i.e. what are the rules?

Comment: I have added column name and expected result.....

Comment: We want to split year in 12 months Like; I have agreement period Annually and Preventive maintenance is 12 in that year then what will be the PM date and what will be the reminder date? like this we want to generate records.

Comment: No one here except you knows what are PM date and reminder date. You should provide minimal sample data that influences output, remove unneeded columns. Explain us how do you determine how to split rows. And put column names to result to make it easier to understand

Comment: @uzi Apologies, I have mentioned description and scenario to understand question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how do you determine how many times your data should be splitted. So this query does not completely solve your issue but may give you an idea. Query calculates values for 6 months. Add extra values in `cross apply` if you need more months

```
declare @t table(
    amcno varchar(50)
    , [date] date
    , custnme varchar(50)
)
insert into @t
values ('ICT/2017-18/1', '20180122', 'MAHESHSHINDE')

select
    t.*, strtdte = dateadd(mm, n - 2, date)
    , endate = dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, n, date))
    , pmdate = dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, n, date))
    , reminder = dateadd(dd, -11, dateadd(mm, n, date))
    , [count] = n / 2
from 
    @t t
    cross apply (values (2), (4), (6), (8), (10), (12)) q(n)
```

Output

```
amcno           date        custnme         strtdte     endate      pmdate      reminder    count
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-01-22  2018-03-21  2018-03-21  2018-03-11    1
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-03-22  2018-05-21  2018-05-21  2018-05-11    2
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-05-22  2018-07-21  2018-07-21  2018-07-11    3
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-07-22  2018-09-21  2018-09-21  2018-09-11    4
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-09-22  2018-11-21  2018-11-21  2018-11-11    5
ICT/2017-18/1   2018-01-22  MAHESHSHINDE    2018-11-22  2019-01-21  2019-01-21  2019-01-11    6
```

Comment: Thanks, but AMC start date is (2018-01-22) and end date is (1/21/2019) we want to make 6 part of year....

Comment: You should have given such an expected output earlier. Two questions. 1) Should not it be `pmdate=2018-03-21` in first row? 2) What is `count` row? You have not mentioned it. Updated query

Comment: Yes right.... I have updated result with pmdate=2018-03-21 and row count. We need 6 rows to get expected result.

Comment: How many rows does my query returns? Does not result match your expected output? The only difference is that I do not have `count` column. But how do I know from where did you get values 1,2,1,1,1,1? And what they mean.

Comment: No, it was 1,2,3,4,5,6. which will show your count of row.

Comment: Usually you would use `row_number` for that. But in this case you have better option. See updated solution. Does it work now? :)

Comment: Thank you so much... this is working fine till 1,2,3,4 and 6. But if we want to make 5,7,8,9,10,11 and 12 parts of year then not getting expected result. Because we need to divide year in 1 to 12 parts.

Comment: @RavirajJadhav, have you solved your issue with the help of this query? If not provide expected output with 12 rows. And explain when you expect your result to be 6 rows, and when it should be 12 rows.

Comment: Sorry for late reply... I will explain you...Just assume we have AMC of computers of particular client and he want 8 preventive maintenance in year. (Preventive maintenance means where engineers clean client computers.) now we want to send notification to engineers 8 times in year. So assume AMC Start date is 01/01/2018 and end date 31/12/2018, so we want to make 8 part of year and will pick one date of every part and send notification to engineers. So this is scenario... Thanks again...